# Rails - acts-as-taggable-on gem - How to change a tag's CSS style depending on it's tag count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, hashtag, acts-as-taggable-on

Tried all sorts of different methods - just can't seem to solve this issue - your help would be amazing!

When a User creates a **Post** they can tag it via the [acts-as-taggable-on gem](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on). If the User writes a tag 2 times or more across Posts I am trying to make that tag then have a different CSS style than the other tags used.

For example, if a user creates three posts: http://imgur.com/zQEWcRo

- **Post1** tagged with "**#foo #bar #foobar**"
- **Post2** tagged with "**#foobar #placeholder**"
- **Post3** tagged with "**#foobar #foo**"

I am trying to get the **#foobar** to have a different CSS style than the other tags (**#foo #bar #placeholder**) across all posts (& preferably move **#foobar** to be the first hashtag in the sequence)

**new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @post, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :tag_list %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**posts_controller.rb**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    if params[:tag]
     @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
   else 
     @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).page(params[:page]).per_page(2)
   end 
 end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="posts">
 <%= render @posts %>
</div>

<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

**_post.html.erb**

```
<div class="post">
 <%= raw post.tag_list.map {|t| link_to t, tag_path(t)}.join(' ') %>
</div> 

<% post.things.order(:order).each do |thing| %>
 <%= thing.try(:text) %>
<% end %>
```

**Schema**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160227154831) do

 create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
 end

create_table "taggings", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "tag_id"
 t.integer  "taggable_id"
 t.string   "taggable_type"
 t.integer  "tagger_id"
 t.string   "tagger_type"
 t.string   "context",       limit: 128
 t.datetime "created_at"
end

add_index "taggings", ["tag_id", "taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context", "tagger_id", "tagger_type"], name: "taggings_idx", unique: true
add_index "taggings", ["taggable_id", "taggable_type", "context"], name: "index_taggings_on_taggable_id_and_taggable_type_and_context"

create_table "tags", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.string  "name"
 t.integer "taggings_count", default: 0
end

add_index "tags", ["name"], name: "index_tags_on_name", unique: true

create_table "things", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.text     "text"
 t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually rather easy. Each acts-as-taggable-on tag has a taggings count.

For example:

```
post.tags.order("taggings_count DESC")
```

for post 1 of your example will give you this:

```
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: some_id, name: "foobar", taggings_count: 3>,  
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: some_id, name: "foo", taggings_count: 2>,
<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag id: some_id, name: "bar", taggings_count: 1>
```

Now you have your tags sorted by number of occurrence and you can also display a different class depending on taggings_count.

**Edit:**

This is how you could render the tags for example:

```
<div class="post">
  <%= raw post.tags.order("taggings_count DESC").map {|t| link_to t.name, tag_path(t.name), class: css_class_for_tag(t.taggings_count)}.join(' ') %>
</div>
```

You will then need to define the helper method css_class_for_tag, for example like this:

```
def css_class_for_tag count
  case count
    when 0
      'new_tag'
    else
      'used_tag' 
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to know whether some tag was used before or not. You can achieve this with:

```
Post.tag_counts_on(:tags).where(name: your_tag_name).present?
```

I'd suggest you to put this into a post.rb like:

```
def self.tag_used?(tag)
  self.tag_counts_on(:tags).where(name: tag.name).present?
end
```

(Switch self with your wanted scope of posts (e.g. user.posts))

So when you know if a tag was used before or not you can add a specific class (let's say 'used') in _post.html.erb (also I suggest you to lookup slim/haml markup languages):

```
<div class="post">
  <%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t), class: ('used' if Post.tag_used?(t)) }.join(' ') %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Unfortunately, I can't seem to get this solution working...I've added my schema to the SO post - I hope this helps! Any feedback would be great - thanks again!